# Visual Studio on Mac using VS2015 failure performance test-- Z: not considered a local drive

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-2012, parallels, diagnostics

I am using a Macbook Air with Parallels(virtual windows machine) and Windows 8.
When trying to run performance diagnostics without debugging/ wizard/ cpu usage on VS2015 Community for a disjointed union coding project for my CS2250 (CS3) class, I get the error: "Performance reports must be created on a local drive. Z:\ is not a local drive. Would  you like to choose a local directory to store your report?" Any thoughts on how to trick VS into using Z:\ as a local drive or some other workaround? I've tried several file paths in both the virtual machine (C:) and the mac (Z:) and nothing seems to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/archive/2011/04/25/performance-reports-must-be-created-on-a-local-drive.aspx

> For better performance, VS Profiler requires the report to be on a local drive.
>
> [...] However, if you absolutely have to use your network drives for that purpose, you can achieve that through usage of Symbolic Links. A symbolic link can be easily created with mklink utility. For example,
>
> mklink /D C:\Foo \\MyNetwork\MyValut
>
> After that you can use C:\Foo as a location for profiling reports. Keep in mind, though, that your network access can be slower than a local drive access, and it can impact your profiling session.

In your case, replace `\\MyNetwork\MyValut` with `Z:\whatever`.

Comment: I would upvote this, but I don't have the experience points. Kudos and thank you.

Comment: @AlanBoxx Glad it helped. I think you can still accept the answer regardless of points, but no worry about it anyway.